# jQuery FullCalendar plugin events are limited to 3 in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I have 8 events specified for my calendar. In Chrome all 8 show up in the calendar for the day. In IE and Firefox only 3 show up? I've tried changing css and scouring the .js file to no avail. Any ideas?

code :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay : 1,
        events: [
            {
                title  : 'event1',
                start  : '2012-10-01 11:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event2',
                start  : '2012-10-01 12:00:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event3 i say i say i say i say',
                start  : '2012-10-01 12:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event and I can\t wait to try it',
                allDay : false // will make the time show
            },
            {
                title  : 'event4',
                start  : '2012-10-01 1:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event5',
                start  : '2012-10-01 2:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event6',
                start  : '2012-10-01 3:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event7',
                start  : '2012-10-01 6:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event8',
                start  : '2012-10-01 7:30:00',
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            }
        ],

        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title + '\nDesc: ' + calEvent.description);
        },

        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

            if (allDay) {
                alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
            }else{
                alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the 24 hour format and prefix a zero if the hour has only one number.

http://jsfiddle.net/mH3pg/

Comment: In your fiddle, I only see 5 events in IE.

Comment: If you look at the code, I intentionally left event7 and 8 untouched to demonstrate that it doesn't work if you don't add the leading zeros.